# What is the easiest way to open a song from MediaLibrary to MediaElement?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I just want to play a song from the audio library.
I know I can use a MediaPlayer like this :

```
using (MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
{
    SongCollection songs = library.Songs;
    Song song = songs[0];
    MediaPlayer.Play(song);
    Song s = songs[0];
}
```

But I want to use my song in a MediaElement. How can I do that ?
I am looking for a method or anything.

```
myMediaElement.Source = song.Source;
```

or

```
myMediaElement.SetSource(song);
```

I am pretty sure there is a way to do it. I am missing something ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible with the current SDK. You can't copy songs from the MediaLibrary to IsolatedStorage and so you can't set the source of the `MediaElement` to that of the song. As far as I'm aware, you can't get the `Stream` of the Song object either via the APIs or third party libraries so you can't use the `SetSource` method.

Comment: Do you have a code snippet or link to do it ?  I will try this for the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to use the MediaElement with songs from the MediaLibrary, so there's no code to show :)

Comment: Ok this explain a lot ... I search all the afternoon a way to do it. I found no doc about it. Well, I guess my question is not silly after all.